# From<frame_support::error::BadOrigin> is not implemented for pallet::Error<T>

Tags: badorigin

For BoundedVec in my storage, this can compile:

```rust
        #[pallet::storage]
        #[pallet::getter(fn members)]
        pub(super) type Members<T: Config> = StorageValue<_, BoundedVec<T::AccountId, T::MaxSize>, ValueQuery>;

        #[pallet::call_index(11)]
        #[pallet::weight(10_000 + T::DbWeight::get().writes(1).ref_time())]
        pub fn add_member(origin: OriginFor<T>) -> DispatchResult {
            let new_member = ensure_signed(origin)?;
          Ok(())
        }
```

but after removing "Ok(())" and adding those below:

```rust
           let mut members = Members::<T>::get();

            match members.binary_search(&new_member) {
                Ok(_) => Err(Error::<T>::AlreadyMember),
                Err(index) => {
                    members.insert(index, new_member.clone());
                    Members::<T>::put(members);
                    Self::deposit_event(Event::MemberAdded{ who: new_member});
                    Ok(())
                }
      }
```

I got this error:

````
  error[E0277]: the trait bound `pallet::Error<T>: From<frame_support::dispatch::DispatchError>` is not satisfied
     --> /mnt/sda3/polkadot/substrate-node-template/pallets/template/src/lib.rs:36:1
      |
  36  | #[frame_support::pallet]
      | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `From<frame_support::dispatch::DispatchError>` is not implemented for `pallet::Error<T>`
      |
  note: required by a bound in `with_storage_layer`
     --> /home/user2038/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/f38bd66/frame/support/src/storage/transactional.rs:172:5
      |
  172 |     E: From<DispatchError>,
      |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `with_storage_layer`
      = note: this error originates in the attribute macro `frame_support::pallet` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

  error[E0277]: `?` couldn't convert the error to `pallet::Error<T>`
     --> /mnt/sda3/polkadot/substrate-node-template/pallets/template/src/lib.rs:266:42
      |
  266 |             let new_member = ensure_signed(origin)?;
      |                                                   ^ the trait `From<frame_support::error::BadOrigin>` is not implemented for `pallet::Error<T>`
      |
      = note: the question mark operation (`?`) implicitly performs a conversion on the error value using the `From` trait
      = help: the following other types implement trait `FromResidual<R>`:
                <Result<T, F> as FromResidual<Result<core::convert::Infallible, E>>>
                <Result<T, F> as FromResidual<Yeet<E>>>
      = note: required for `Result<_, pallet::Error<T>>` to implement `FromResidual<Result<core::convert::Infallible, frame_support::error::BadOrigin>>`

  error[E0308]: mismatched types
     --> /mnt/sda3/polkadot/substrate-node-template/pallets/template/src/lib.rs:36:1
      |
  36  | #[frame_support::pallet]
      | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `Result<(), DispatchError>`, found `Result<(), Error<T>>`
  ...
  265 |         pub fn add_member(origin: OriginFor<T>) -> DispatchResult {
      |                                                    -------------- expected `Result<(), frame_support::dispatch::DispatchError>` because of return type
      |
      = note: expected enum `Result<_, frame_support::dispatch::DispatchError>`
                 found enum `Result<_, pallet::Error<T>>`
      = note: this error originates in the attribute macro `frame_support::pallet` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
  help: use `?` to coerce and return an appropriate `Err`, and wrap the resulting value in `Ok` so the expression remains of type `Result`
```      |
````

Somehow adding the match statement is causing the error to happen! Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```rust
Ok(_) => Err(Error::<T>::AlreadyMember),
```

should be

```rust
Ok(_) => Err(Error::<T>::AlreadyMember.into()),
```

Comment: Thank you man. This is the answer!